# Trying to merge 2 objects using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge two reports (Objects) together, and if the objects share the same property, I need to loop through the property and sum the values up inside it. Here is a small example of two objects that need merging/summing:

```
var houses = {
    "red" = {
        alpha: {
            "2017": 100,
            "2018": 140,
            "2019": 99
        },
        beta: {
            "2017": 0,
            "2018": 25,
            "2019": 900
        }
    },
    "blue": {
        beta: {
            "2017": 10,
            "2018": 240,
            "2019": 60
        },
        charlie: {
            "2017": 25,
            "2018": 0,
            "2019": 60
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I would like the result of the merge to look like:

```
var merged = {
    alpha: {
        "2017": 100,
        "2018": 140,
        "2019": 99
    },
    beta: {
        "2017": 10,
        "2018": 265,
        "2019": 960
    },
    charlie: {
        "2017": 25,
        "2018": 0,
        "2019": 60
    }
}
```

So I need to loop through the houses and add the properties of each house to a new "merged" object. Once the iterator finds a property that is already a part of the new "merged" variable (in this case, "beta"), I would like to total the values inside it. Here is a fiddle that I'm using that I can't get to work yet. Can anyone help me out with this?

**This is what I have tried:**

```js
var objects = {
  "foo": {
    a: {
      "2017": 100,
      "2018": 140,
      "2019": 99
    },
    b: {
      "2017": 0,
      "2018": 25,
      "2019": 900
    }
  },
  "bar": {
    b: {
      "2017": 10,
      "2018": 240,
      "2019": 60
    },
    c: {
      "2017": 25,
      "2018": 0,
      "2019": 60
    }
  }
}

var merged = {};

function merge(target, source) {
  for (const prop in source) {
    if (target.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (Number.isInteger(target[prop])) {
        target[prop] = target[prop] + source[prop];
      } else {
        target.data[prop] = merge(target[prop], source[prop]);
      }
    } else {
      target[prop] = source[prop];
    }
  }

  return target;
}


for (var prop in objects) {
  merged[prop] = objects[prop];
  for (var key in objects[prop]) {
    if (merged[prop].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log('hop: ' + key);
      var blah = merge(merged[prop][key], objects[prop][key]);
      console.log(blah);
    } else {
      merged[prop][key] = objects[prop][key];
    }
  }
}

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior if `houses.red.alpha` is an `object` and `houses.blue.alpha` is a `number`?

Comment: @Paarth I would just account for that by checking if the value is a number or not. If the value is an object, I would want to pass the object back into the merge function to process the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get a flattened array of all inner objects that you want to merge with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). Then you can merge all of them (summing common counts) with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var houses = {
  "red": {
    alpha: {
      "2017": 100,
      "2018": 140,
      "2019": 99
    },
    beta: {
      "2017": 0,
      "2018": 25,
      "2019": 900
    }
  },
  "blue": {
    beta: {
      "2017": 10,
      "2018": 240,
      "2019": 60
    },
    charlie: {
      "2017": 25,
      "2018": 0,
      "2019": 60
    }
  }
};

var merged = Object.values(houses)
  .flatMap(Object.entries)
  .reduce((acc, [alphabet, years]) => {
    acc[alphabet] = acc[alphabet] || {};
    Object.entries(years).forEach(([year, val]) => {
      acc[alphabet][year] = acc[alphabet][year] || 0;
      acc[alphabet][year] += val;
    });
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this monstrosity.

```js
const houses = {
  "red": {
    alpha: { "2017": 100, "2018": 140, "2019": 99 },
    beta: { "2017": 0, "2018": 25, "2019": 900 },
   },
  "blue": {
    beta: { "2017": 10, "2018": 240, "2019": 60 },
    charlie: { "2017": 25, "2018": 0, "2019": 60 },
  }
}

const result = Object.keys(houses).reduce((res, key) => {
  Object.keys(houses[key]).forEach(k => {
    if (!(k in res)) res[k] = {};
    Object.keys(houses[key][k]).map(_k => {
      res[k][_k] = (res[k][_k] || 0) + houses[key][k][_k];
    });
  });
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const houses = {
  red: {
    alpha: {
      "2017": 100,
      "2018": 140,
      "2019": 99
    },
    beta: {
      "2017": 0,
      "2018": 25,
      "2019": 900
    }
  },
  blue: {
    beta: {
      "2017": 10,
      "2018": 240,
      "2019": 60
    },
    charlie: {
      "2017": 25,
      "2018": 0,
      "2019": 60
    }
  }
};

function merge(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const currentColor = obj[cur];

    for (let key in currentColor) {
      if (acc[key]) {
        for (let x in currentColor[key]) {
          if (acc[key][x]) {
            acc[key][x] += currentColor[key][x];
          } else {
            acc[key][x] = currentColor[key][x];
          }
        }
      } else {
        acc[key] = currentColor[key];
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(merge(houses))
```

You can use reduce. Example here https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-grass-fk0f3

Here the idea is to loop the first layer of object in this case `red` and `blue`. After this you need to continuing loop inside those but you also need to keep a state between. For the sum you need also to make sure the result object do have the key already. If not this will cause issue when you do `+=`

```
 export function merge(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const currentColor = obj[cur];

    for (let key in currentColor) {
      if (acc[key]) {
        for (let x in currentColor[key]) {
          if (acc[key][x]) {
            acc[key][x] += currentColor[key][x];
          } else {
            acc[key][x] = currentColor[key][x];
          }
        }
      } else {
        acc[key] = currentColor[key];
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```